# my firebase doesnt create accounts (connected from an android studio java project) when i create them even tho it is successfully connected?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I connected my Firebase to my project by adding the needed implementations and permissions and also using the conference short and straight I followed exactly the tutorial there is no error at all and I tried debugging and it shows that everything is fine but when I try and create a new account my Firebase doesn't add any users into it and I can't know why and it is confusing me because I need to get this project done as soon as possible.

Comment: share your code?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Praveen asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.